# If $\,\Delta_{\scriptsize\mathbb{R}^n}u = \lambda u\,$ and $\,u(x)=u(x+y)$, then $\,u_{y}(x):=e^{2 \pi i \left\langle x,y\right\rangle}$

Tags: proof-verification, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

Related to [Analysis on Manifolds via the Laplacian](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/toth/spectral%20geometry.pdf) page $52$, I would like someone explain to me why if we have a function $u$ such that $\,\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^{n\,}}u = \lambda u\,$ and $u(x)=u(x+y)$ with $y \in \Gamma^*$, then this function have to be on the form $\,u_{y}(x):=e^{2 \pi i \left\langle x,y\right\rangle}$? I have some ideas, but it is confusing actually. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is not the general form of such a function $u$. After taking a look at your reference I got an impression that $\,e^{2 \pi i \left\langle x,y\right\rangle}\,$  is just _a function_ satisfying all the constraints.

Comment: How could we sure we could find the Spectrum of $\mathbb(T)$ with $u_y(x)$

Comment: @Vlad So how could we sure that we find all eigenfunctions of the torus.

Comment: It is shown in the book that $\left\lbrace u_y(x)\mid y\in \Gamma^∗\right\rbrace$, therefore in every nonempty space of eigenfunctions corresponding to certain eigenvalue $\lambda$ there will be at least one function with nonzero projection to at least one of  basis functions
$u_y(x)$.